# Horizontally & Vertically centering 2 divs within two side by side 50% width columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

Having some trouble getting 2 divs to center horizontally & vertically within their respective parents which are side by side with 50% width and 100% height.

Here's what I've got (Codepen for ease).

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/jacobbanner/pen/YwamWg?editors=1100)

```
*** HTML ***
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="info">
      <h1>This div should be centered <br>within the left 50%</h1>
      <h2>Get in touch:</h2>
      <h1>
        +44 (0)1323 567 891<br>
        +44 (0)1323 132 363<br>
        info@somecompany.co.uk<br>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/210x210/FE5000/FFF"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div

*** CSS ***
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent:before, .parent:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
 }

.parent:after {
  clear: both;
}

.left, .right {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.info {
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.right .img-wrapper {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. I added display: flex; to the .left and .right classes.

```
.parent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.left, .right {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
}

.info {
    width: 400px;
    height: 280px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Solved it!
Adding display flex is the right way about it here, I noticed you put the height as a pixel value, which removes any vertical responsiveness, and whilst a percentage value doesn't work, I remembered that VH units do.
Thanks for your help!

Here's the solution:
http://codepen.io/jacobbanner/pen/mVLbbP?editors=1100

Comment: No problem at all Jacob. Glad I could help.